# Port forwarding - DNS сервер

Tags: linux, iptables

Сеть создана таким обзором:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все компьютера пигуются на все IP адреса а также имеют доступ к интернету.

На машине `192.168.0.155` стоят несколько правил в `iptables`

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.155 --dport 33 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.167:22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.155 --dport 88 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.167:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.155 --dport 5540 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.167:554
```

DNS сервер также установлен и настроен на `192.168.0.155`. Проблема в том, что отпинговать со второй машины `192.168.2.167` `ping google.com`я не могу, а IP адрес гугл спокойно. В чем проблема?

Comment: а 192.168.0.155 установлен как dns сервер на 192.168.2.167 ?

Comment: @zb' да, про это я не забыл )

Comment: Какая OS на  192.168.2.167 ? и в любом случае попробуйте 
`dig google.com @localhost` на 192.168.2.155, если на второй linux, то тоже попробуйте `dig google.com @192.168.2.167 `

Comment: Покажи результат `nslookup google.com 192.168.2.155`

Comment: @dsnk http://prntscr.com/8x3f1d

Comment: @zb' http://prntscr.com/8x3fd1 - armDebian

Comment: а сорри, я имел ввиду с 192.168.2.167  `dig google.com @192.168.2.155` и заодно находясь на 192.168.2.167 `dig google.com`

в общем если это все работает, то скорее всего и пинг работает :)

Comment: @Insider это было выполнено с `192.168.2.167`? , если да, то в качестве DNS надо прописать 192.168.2.155. Покажи `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @dsnk выполнено с `192.168.0.155 / 192.168.2.155`. DNS на `192.168.2.167` прописан как `192.168.2.155`. Вот `resolv.conf`- `nameserver 192.168.2.155`

Comment: @zb' на `192.168.2.167` функции `dig` нету и установить я её туда не смогу. Есть другие варианты?

Comment: nslookup как говорил @dsnk

Comment: Вот `nslookup` с `192.168.2.167` http://prntscr.com/8x3jwh

Comment: т.е. просто `nslookup google.com` работает ? 
если нет, то что у него в шапке написано насчет `server`

Comment: @zb' просто, работает. То есть, что написано?

Comment: значит и ping работать должен, если `ping 42.119.208.222` и  `nslookup google.com` работают с одной машины, то `ping google.com` не работать c этой же машины не может.

Comment: @zb' я честно не понимаю как, но `nslookup google.com` с 192.168.2.167 работает, а вот пинг с неё, нет. 

P.S. 192.168.0.155 и 192.168.2.155 - это одна машина,
192.168.2.167 другая

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30913/discussion-between-zb-and-insider).

Comment: @zb' мы можем продолжить?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, включен ли  ip forward. 
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward должен быть 1.

Comment: он включен, иначе бы правила в iptables и интернет не работали.